# Stop UISearchBar from scrolling with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

I have one `UITableViewController` and I have implemented `UISearchBarController` bellow navigation bar. My issue is that when I scroll `UITableView`, my `UISearchBar` acts as a `UITableView` cell, and scrolls like any other cell. I want to fix position of `UISearchBar`. My storyboard looks like "[This](https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAf0Js_22MSv5NVoelV9FXOt6-JQgImlKo1ynmCtLZdLQ/12/290486623/png/32x32/3/_/1/2/Screenshot%202014-05-17%2020.25.02.png/xkVOw1kFtLc_1QqeqZRRp9mFAoYXMRrc1TZCAL7dEaw?size=1280x960)".

Comment: Add set the search bar as tableHeaderView property of UITableView, or if you are using storyboard, it is possible to add searchbar to tableview header directly.

Comment: simply drag a searchbar to tableviewcontroller & drop it in header. that will be added as table view header , and will not scroll with your table. check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view)

Answer (score -1):

You could do this **directly within storyboard** but if you you want to do it in code then it would be like this,

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Or it would probably be easy if you do this in storyboard itself. That way, you could also assign the **searchbar** to **searchDisplayController** and so it becomes easier to implement search function.

Comment: I didn't mention that i have added UISearchViewController to my UITableViewController. Method above doesn't work and it's driving me crazy.